# Javascript no almacena en array largas cadenas de string por elemento

Tags: javascript, html, array, filereader

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes al querer guardar strings demasiado largos dentro de un array en javascript.

En sí, la idea es simple, tengo un elemento input de tipo file en donde un usuario puede subir múltiples imágenes.

Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al momento en el que usuario termine de elegir sus imágenes, yo dispare un evento (con un onchange) que lee cada una de las imágenes seleccionadas por el usuario y almacenarlas en un array con la apí de FileReader.

Tengo un ciclo for, el cual recorre cada elemento (o imagen) y la convierto en un string base64, el problema que tengo es que mi array aparece vacío después de terminar el ciclo y no sé por qué, ya que necesito tener guardados estos strings para ocuparlos después.

Dejo mi código que estoy ocupando.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".subir-imagenes-principales", function() {
  $('.file-subir-imagenes-principales').click();
});

$("body").on("change", ".file-subir-imagenes-principales", function() {
  

  if ( $(this).val() != '' ) {
   var input = this;
   var images = [];
   for ( item_image = 0; item_image < input.files.length; item_image++ ) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function(e) {
       var result = e.target.result;
       console.log("base64 obtenido --> "+ result);
            //en esta parte guardo este string en mi array images
       images.push(result);
     }

     reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[item_image]);
   }
      //y justo aquí al momento de querer qué se guardó, javascript lo interpreta como vacío
      console.log("imprimiendo array con strings almacenados previamente en el for ---> \n");
   console.log(images);


  }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="subir-imagenes-principales" href="#!">Subir imágenes</a>
<input accept="image/*" type="file" class="file-subir-imagenes-principales" style="display:none;" id="" name="file-subir-imagenes-principales" multiple>
```

Comment: El problema es que cuando llamas a `console.log` tu `fileReader` aún no ha terminado de procesar los datos. Debes usar el evento [`loadend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Events/loadend) para mostrar el resultado. Más información en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL). Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que `FileReader` es asíncrono. Significa que tienes el *array* de `string` **después** de que lo imprimas.

Se pueden usar `Promise` para esperar a los `FileReader` que acaben su trabajo y entonces seguir con el código.

Primero, encapsulamos el trabajo del `FileReader` en una función que devuelva una `Promise`. La `Promise` resolverá el `string` resultado del *reader*.

```
const readItem = item =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    // Resolvemos la Promise con el resultado del reader
    reader.onload(e => resolve(e.target.result));
    // También debemos rechazar la Promise en caso de error
    reader.onerror(reject);

    reader.readAsDataURL(item);
  });
```

Después, en vez de recorrer las imágenes con un `for`, vamos a obtener un *array* de `Promise`, una por cada elemento en `input.files`.

```
const { files } = input;

// Convertimos la FileList a File[]
// También se puede hacer con la deconstrucción (ES6)
// const fileArray = [...files];
const fileArray = Array.from(files);
const promises = fileArray.map(readItem);
```

Finalmente, esperamos a que todas las `Promise` se resuelvan. Podemos hacerlo con `Promise.all`.

```
Promise.all(promises)
  .then(images => {
    // En este punto tienes tu array de strings
  })
  .catch(console.error);
```

**EDIT:**
Solucionado el *bug*

> Uncaught TypeError: files.map is not a function

Ya que `files` es de tipo `FileList` y no *array*.
Podemos convertir la `FileList` a *array* con `Array.from()` o deconstruyendo el objeto.

```
const array = Array.from(files);
const array = [...files];
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias por tu tan elaborada y buena respuesta. Intenté ocupar el código que me explicaste pero estoy recibiendo este error, ¿a qué se deberá? Nunca he trabajado con promesas en javascript y estoy un poco perdido en encontrar la solución: `Uncaught TypeError: files.map is not a function`

Comment: Tienes razón, fue error mío. el objeto `files` es una `FileList`, no un *array*, por lo que no tiene el método `map` del *Prototype Array*. Voy a modificar la respuesta para corregirlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora sí sirvió y ya tengo mi array lleno. Saludos, amigo!